# Wro4j plugin versus wro4j filter

Tags: maven, spring-boot, wro4j

I am using spring boot and have to profile my application to dev profile and release profile.
At the same time want to use wro4j.
In dev profile, i have to use wro4j plugin or using filter ?
The same for release mode , what i have to put ?

Comment: Never use wro4j filter in production environment, since runtime processing of resources will consume a lot of computing resources & memory.

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice

Comment: Actually, we end up write our own Thylemeaf Wro4jDialect and serve the plain front resources directly in `development` profile. And serve bundled resources created by wro4j maven plugin in `production`.
However, we are using pure frontend technologies for our web project currently.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends what you need it for, runtime or also buildtime solution?

Run time solution you may have to add the filter and tehen configure it depending on the environment (dev or release) take a look:

```
http://wro4j.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ConfigureWro4jViaSpring/
```

for build time you will have to add the maven dependency.

Comment: using wro4j maven plug in in both profile dev and release mode ?

Comment: actually I edited my answer (after 2nd thinking on this).